# pass two strings from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a tic tac toe application for android. In the Two player section, I've created an activity which will ask the two players to enter their names. For that I've used two `EditTexts`. The problem is That my app force closes while starting the next activity. Here is my code:

```
//Activity 1:
    EditText player1field,player2field;
    Button startbutton;
    Intent startbuttonintent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_options);
    setupActionBar();
    player1field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1field);
    player2field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2field);
    startbuttonintent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String player1name = player1field.getText().toString();
            String player2name = player2field.getText().toString();
            startbuttonintent.putExtra("PLAYER1NAME",player1name);
            startbuttonintent.putExtra("PLAYER2NAME",player2name);
            startActivity(startbuttonintent);
        }
    });
}
```

this is activity 2

```
//Activity2
Intent startbuttonintent = getIntent();
TextView p1name,p2name;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3m);

    String player1name = startbuttonintent.getStringExtra("PLAYER1NAME");
    String player2name = startbuttonintent.getStringExtra("PLAYER2NAME");
    p1name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1name);
    p2name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2name);
    p1name.setText(player1name);
    p2name.setText(player2name);
}
```

This code is not giving me any errors but my app force closes when I run it.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use putExtra to Intent

Comment: Why cant you pass HashMap or Array

Comment: @MT8 I didn't get you.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke please have a look at my answer !!!!!!!!!

Comment: try this way getIntent().getStringExtra("PLAYER1NAME");
    getIntent().getStringExtra("PLAYER2NAME");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Activity 1:**

```
    EditText player1field,player2field;
    Button startbutton;
    Intent startbuttonintent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_options);
    setupActionBar();
    player1field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1field);
    player2field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2field);        
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String player1name = player1field.getText().toString();
            String player2name = player2field.getText().toString();
            startbuttonintent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startbuttonintent.putExtra("PLAYER1NAME",player1name);
            startbuttonintent.putExtra("PLAYER2NAME",player2name);
            startActivity(startbuttonintent);
        }
    });
}
```

You have call this method before **onclick** which is causing error.

And fetch the intent text like this:

**//Activity2**

```
TextView p1name,p2name;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_3m);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  String player1name = extras.getString("PLAYER1NAME");
  String player2name = extras.getString("PLAYER2NAME");
  p1name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1name);
  p2name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2name);
  p1name.setText(player1name);
  p2name.setText(player2name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String intArray[] = {"one","two"};
Intent in = new Intent(this, B.class);
in.putExtra("my_array", intArray);
startActivity(in);
```

For Reading :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] arrayInB = extras.getStringArray("my_array");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take yout `getIntent` method inside `onCreate` method

//Activity2

```
TextView p1name,p2name;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3m);
    Intent startbuttonintent = getIntent();

    String player1name = startbuttonintent.getStringExtra("PLAYER1NAME");
    String player2name = startbuttonintent.getStringExtra("PLAYER2NAME");
    p1name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1name);
    p2name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2name);
    p1name.setText(player1name);
    p2name.setText(player2name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `Intent startbuttonintent = getIntent();` to inside your `onCreate()` method

`getIntent()` is a method in `Activity`, so you can't call it in a static class level initialization. You must call it only after your `Activity` object is ready, like when in the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

@Chinmay Dabke  Please get the id of the button "startbutton"

by  using

```
startbutton = (Button)findviewbyId(R.id.startbutton);
```

Comment: Yes I've done that. Forgot to add it in my question.

Comment: can you please provide the Log getting printed while its force close

Answer (score 0):

Try This....in `Activity1`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle .putString("PLAYER1NAME",player1name);
bundle .putString("PLAYER2NAME",player2name);
intent1.putExtras(bundle);
```

in `Activity2`

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String player1name = b.getString("PLAYER1NAME");
String player2name = b.getString("PLAYER2NAME");
```